# Why does this dict give me a syntax error?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
#create a mapping of state to abbreviation
states = [
    'Oregon': 'OR',
    'Florida': 'FL',
    'California': 'CA',
    'New York': 'NY',
    'Michigan': 'MI',
]
```

I'm working through Learn Python the Hard Way, and this lesson has me stumped. I've looked everywhere, but I can't figure out why it's giving me this error :

```
oldlink:my-python HarveyMark$ python ex39.py
  File "ex39.py", line 3
    'Oregon': 'OR',
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: dicts are enclosed by {}, not []

Comment: Dictionary literals are wrapped in curly braces: `{'a': 'b'}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `[` it indicates that you are defining a `list` , not a `dict`.

For a dict use `{` and `}`. Example -

```
states = {
    'Oregon': 'OR',
    'Florida': 'FL',
    'California': 'CA',
    'New York': 'NY',
    'Michigan': 'MI',
}
```

Comment: Huh, the book said to use [ ]. That worked, thanks for curing my headache!

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, `dictionaries` use curly brackets `{}`.

The correct code is:

```
states = {
    'Oregon': 'OR',
    'Florida': 'FL',
    'California': 'CA',
    'New York': 'NY',
    'Michigan': 'MI',
}
```

Just to clarify your error, you used square brackets (which are used for `lists`). The error states that it was expecting a comma to separate the elements rather than a colon.